# set time limit for quiz module

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, forms

Need little help with the quiz problem.

I want to set time limit for each question in quiz module (say 30 seconds) and after that time, the
form will auto submit the question (auto submit = no option selected = unanswered).

There are 3 questions, so total time limit is 90 sec  (30 sec each).

I'm doing this via XAMPP.

The link below provide the work so far

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4dzlgjtjzvs48vw/quiz.rar?dl=0

Thanks

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I am working on a quiz app using php and mysql and now I need a modifiaction,which is auto submit a question if not answered in a given time limit

Comment: I ask again, what's your question? What have you tried? What do you need help with? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @JoesephHanh, Please check my below answer for your solution.

Comment: @Joe Fitter, in that case, you need to take a look at the link I've provided thanks

Answer (score 1):

@Joeseph, You need to count total time for your question module.

***Process Flow for quiz module***

**For Example :**

Suppose total 3 question then you need to multiply 3 * 30 = 90 seconds. So You got 90 seconds at server side.

After that you can use below method (**Dependency** - **Include jQuery library**) for auto submit form process.

```
setTimeout(function(){ //Your form submit code }, 90000);
```

The `setTimeout()` method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds.

**Note :**

1000 ms = 1 second.

The function is only executed once. If you need to repeat execution, use the `setInterval()` method.

Let me know if you still have any questions or issues.

Comment: can you provide me the code, this link https://www.dropbox.com/s/4dzlgjtjzvs48vw/quiz.rar?dl=0  contains the work so far thanks

Comment: @JoesephHanh, I have mentioned the process you need to work accordingly to resolve your problem. Let me know if you stuck anywhere so I will help you. You  can accept/up-vote my answer if my answer help you ! Thanks in adv.